# Unterschied zwischen "aufbrühen" und "aufgießen"

Tags: difference

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "aufbrühen" und "aufgießen"?

Edit: Unfortunately I don't understand tinny difference between these words and Duden doesn't have too much information about it.

Comment: Was sagt denn dein Wörterbuch dazu?

Comment: Duden sagt nichts.

Comment: Den Unterschied zwischen *brühen* und *gießen* kennst du auch nicht?

Comment: @tillias: the level of tolerance for easy-looking questions is different among our user base. Closing (and reopening) is almost exclusively done by the community but if you feel there was something done wrong you may flag your post for moderator attention or - even better - discuss this matter on [meta]. I removed the meta-complaints from your question which hopefully became obsolete after reopening.

Comment: Other than that [chat] also is a good place to discuss such matters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Beim *Aufbrühen* wird immer eine kochende Flüssigkeit verwendet, meist um etwas (auf-)zulösen (z.B. Tee, Suppenwürfel, Kaffee). Im Gegensatz dazu wird beim *Aufgießen* eine Flüssigkeit von oben nachgefüllt (gegossen). Die Temperatur der der Flüssigkeit (z.B. *Ich gieße den Rumtopf mit frischem Alkohol auf*)  ist dabei im Gegensatz zu *Aufbrühen* irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

"Aufbrühen" sagt man vor allem beim Zubereiten von Tee oder Kaffee. Siehe auch der [Duden-Artikel zu "Aufbrühen"](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/aufbruehen).

> "Tee bitte immer mit frisch gekochtem Wasser aufbrühen!"

"Aufgießen" ist ein etwas allgemeinerer Begriff, den man z.B. auch bei der Zubereitung von Braten verwendet:

> "Gießen Sie den Braten mit Rotwein auf, um eine schmackhafte Soße zu bekommen."

Auch hierzu hilft der [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/aufgieszen) weiter.

Comment: Vielen Dank, leider sagt Duden nicht zu viel

Comment: @tillias: Bei Duden gibt es auch einen Abschnitt "Bedeutungsübersicht", in dem die Bedeutungen mit Beispielsätzen erläutert werden.

Comment: Ich benutze Duden seit ca. 3 Jahren, aber in dieser Situation brauchе ich die Unterstützung des Muttersprachlers um genauen Unterschied zu verstehen. Ich habe die richtige Antwort markiert, Danke

Comment: Nur als Hilfe habe ich den Satz korrigiert: Ich benutze den Duden seit ca. 3 Jahren, aber in dieser Situation brauchе ich die Unterstützung des Muttersprachlers um den genauen Unterschied zu verstehen.
Das Wort -den- darf hier nicht fehlen.